# Repaint JPanel from different class

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I'm having problems repainting a class after I have added an object to it.

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private MediaHandler myMediaHandler = new MediaHandler(this);

class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String buttonText = e.getActionCommand();
        switch(buttonText) {
        case "Add Movie":
            AddMovieWindow addMovieGUI = new AddMovieWindow(myMediaHandler);
            addMovieGUI.setVisible(true);
            break;
        case "Add TV-Show":
            AddTVShowWindow addTVShowGUI = new AddTVShowWindow(myMediaHandler);
            addTVShowGUI.setVisible(true);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public Window() {
//  myMediaHandler.addMovie("Nineteen Eighty-Four", 113.00, 1984, "Michael Radford", "mediaPath", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16670644/Projekt/1984.png", "HD", false, "Eng", "George Orwell (novel)");
    addComponents();
    configurFrame();
    addMenu();

    validate();
    repaint();
}

private void addMenu() {
    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
    bar.add(menu);

    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Add Movie");
    item.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
    menu.add(item);

    item = new JMenuItem("Add TV-Show");
    item.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
    menu.add(item);

    this.setJMenuBar(bar);
}

private void configurFrame() {
    this.setSize(1205, 850);
    this.setTitle("Video Library");
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("E:\\Dropbox\\Dropbox\\Programmering\\Java\\Projekt IV 1\\icon.png").getImage());

    try {
        java.net.URL where = new URL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16670644/Projekt/BackGround.png");
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(where);
        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image);
        this.add(imageLabel);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Error loading Background that makes the background image");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void addComponents() {
    JPanel shelfs = buildShelfs();
    this.add(shelfs);
}

private JPanel buildShelfs() {
    JPanel mediaPanel = new JPanel();
    int nrOfMedias = myMediaHandler.mediaList.size();
    mediaPanel.setOpaque(false);
    mediaPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,6,22,30));
    mediaPanel.setBounds(90, 25, 1020, 745);

            java.net.URL where;
            for(int i = 0; i < nrOfMedias; i++) {
                String temp = myMediaHandler.mediaList.get(i).getImagePath();
                try {
                    where = new URL(temp);
                    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(where);
                    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image);
                    mediaPanel.add(imageLabel);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("Error loading user media picture");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        java.net.URL where1;
        try {
            for(int i = nrOfMedias; i < 18; i++) {
                where1 = new URL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16670644/Projekt/TempPic.png");
                ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(where1);           
                JLabel imageLabel1 = new JLabel(image1);
                mediaPanel.add(imageLabel1);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Error loading TempPic that shows allowed media spots");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mediaPanel;
}

public static void main(String[] arg) {
    Window mainWindowGUI = new Window();
    mainWindowGUI.setVisible(true);
}   
}
```

What i'm trying to do now is from another class calling the rapaint function.

```
public class MediaHandler {
ArrayList<Media> mediaList;

private Window myWindow;

public MediaHandler(Window window) {
    this.mediaList = new ArrayList<Media>();
    myWindow = window;
}

public void addMovie(String title, Double playTime, int year,
        String directory, String mediaPath, String imagePath, String quality,
        boolean subtitles, String language, String writer) {
    mediaList.add(new Movie(title, playTime, year, false, directory, mediaPath, imagePath, rating.unrated, quality, subtitles, language, writer));

    myWindow.getContentPane().invalidate();
    myWindow.invalidate();

}   
}
```

Please let me know if there is anything which is unclear! I have been stuck on this problem for a few days now.

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear. Please explain in details. Where have you been stuck?

Comment: Either `MediaHandler` doesn't call `repaint`, or I'm missing something.

Comment: The buildShelfs function adds images of movie posters. And if i add a new movie the buildShelf area needs to be repainted in order for the images to show. [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16670644/programImg.PNG) This image shows a run of the program, if i now add a new object to my array i want it to be displayed as well and that essentially is my problem.

Nothe that the first iteration in the buildShelfs function gets the url from the arrayList and i have verified that i actually can add new movies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a lot of code, and not really cleanly structured and so. But as far as I can see, the problem can not solved by only "repaining" anything. The problem is that the labels (showing the media images) are not added to the shelf.

You are currently calling the `buildShelfs` method **once**, when the frame is constructed. When you are later adding a new movie via the `MediaHandler`, you are adding this movie to the `mediaList`. But you are **not** adding a new label/image to the `mediaPanel`.

This can probably be solved as follows: You can declare the `mediaPanel` as an instance variable. And you can offer a method to add a new `ImageIcon` to this panel, with an image that was read from a particular URL (given as a String). This method can on the one hand be used during the initialization (that is, during the first call to `buildShelfs`). But more importantly: You can also call this method from the `MediaHandler`, so that a new ImageIcon is added to the `mediaPanel` whenever a new movie is added in the `MovieHandler`.

I tried to sketch the basic idea in the following code. But again, the structure of the current code is not really nice and clean, so there was some guesswork involved....

```
class Window ... 
{
    // Store this as an instance variable
    private JPanel mediaPanel;


    private JPanel buildShelfs()
    {
        mediaPanel = new JPanel();
        mediaPanel.setOpaque(false);
        mediaPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 6, 22, 30));
        mediaPanel.setBounds(90, 25, 1020, 745);
        for (int i=0; i<18; i++)
        {
            addMedia(i);
        }
        return mediaPanel;
    }


    private void addMedia(int index)
    {
        // You should store these images LOCALLY!!!
        String urlString = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16670644/Projekt/TempPic.png";

        int nrOfMedias = myMediaHandler.mediaList.size();
        if (index < nrOfMedias)
        {
            urlString = myMediaHandler.mediaList.get(i).getImagePath();
        }
        addMedia(urlString);
    }

    void addMedia(String urlString)
    {
        try
        {
            java.net.URL where = new URL(urlString);
            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(where);
            JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image);
            mediaPanel.add(imageLabel);
            mediaPanel.invalidate();
            mediaPanel.validate();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error loading user media picture from "+urlString);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}




class MediaHandler 
{
    ArrayList<Media> mediaList;

    private Window myWindow;

    public MediaHandler(Window window) 
    {
        this.mediaList = new ArrayList<Media>();
        myWindow = window;
    }

    public void addMovie(String title, Double playTime, int year,
        String directory, String mediaPath, String imagePath, String quality,
        boolean subtitles, String language, String writer) 
    {
        mediaList.add(new Movie(title, playTime, year, 
            false, directory, mediaPath, imagePath, rating.unrated, 
            quality, subtitles, language, writer));

        myWindow.addMedia(mediaPath);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i do realise that the structure of the code is not nice at all. However this is my first "bigger" GUI and as a bonus im used to working with c++ but i'm learning. Once again thanks!